# Retrieving month name with the month number

Tags: java, android

I'm modifying a calendar and there is a case where I'm given a month number and I need to compare it with a month name.

Of course, I could create a switch statement, but I was wondering if I can obtain the month name from the number or vice versa to do the conditional.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you compare the `int` number with `Calendar`'s month constants (i.e., `JANUARY`, `AUGUST`, etc.), there won't be a problem with having the number instead of the name.

Here's a way to get the actual name, if you need it:

```
String getMonthForInt(int m) {
    DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols();
    String[] months = dfs.getMonths();
    if (m >= 0 && m <= 11 ) {
        return months[m];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Taken from [here](http://bluebones.net/2002/10/converting-month-number-to-month-name-in-java/).

Answer (score 2):

Store the month names in a `List<String>`, and use `list.indexOf(monthName)` to find its index (number starting from 0), and `list.get(index)` to get the name of a given month number (still starting from 0).